# markdown: use HTML code to render pdf output?

Tags: r, r-markdown

Is there way to use html codes like div for R markdown rendered to pdf? Here is an example.

````
---
pdf_document:
  fig_caption: yes
toc: yes
output: pdf_document
always_allow_html: yes
---

    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
    ```

    ## R Markdown
    <hr>
    <div style="background-color: orange;">
    Hi there!
    </div>
````

If I rendered this to html it will give an orange background with "Hi There!" however if I output this to pdf the orange div goes away.  Is it possible to have it rendered to pdf with the orange div background? thanks!